# For loop in R: exporting many files in once

Tags: r

I have many datasets stored in a list and I wrote this function to export them all at once. It loops by list and finds if they are csv or excel file and writes them. When I run the code I get the following error "Error in if (grep("+csv", names(mylist[i])) == T) { : 
  argument is of length zero"

any help is appreciated. My code is as it follows:

````
    for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
      if (grep("+csv", names(mylist[i])) == T) {
        write.csv(mylist[[i]], paste0(i, ".csv"))
        } 
      else if (grep("+xlsx|+xls", names(mylist[i])) == T) {
              write.xlsx(mylist[[i]], paste0(i, ".xlsx"))
      }
      }} ```
````

Comment: Could you provide the list?  It might be that your regular expression does not return any result. What happens when you only run the grep funcion? (Outside of the loop and the if statements)

Comment: I think you want `grepl` not `grep`. The "l` in `grepl` is for "logical" - it returns TRUE or FALSE. `grep` is equivalent to `which(grepl(...))`, so if there isn't a match it will return an empty value.

Comment: 1) `names(mylist)[i]`; 2) Use `grepl`, that condition compares integers with logical `T`; 3) If you do use `grepl`, remove the `== T` part it's not needed. 4) Remove the plus signs.

Comment: The conditions then become `if(grepl("csv", names(mylist)[i]))` and `if(grepl("xls|xlsx", names(mylist)[i]))`. The second condition can be simplified to `if(grepl("xlsx*$", names(mylist)[i]))`

Comment: I think it should be grep("+csv", names(mylist[i])) == 1  and grep("+xlsx|+xls", names(mylist[i])) == 1

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. I have deleted the conditions from my function and just used grepl as Gregor and Rui had mentioned  `grepl("csv", names(mylist)[i]))` 
 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram that still won't work when there isn't a match. `grep("a", "b")` returns `integer(0)`, and `if(integer(0) == 1){}` still throws an error. If you **really** want to use `grep` rather than `grepl` you could do `if(length(grep(...)))`, but there are no advantages to that over the simpler `if(grepl(...))`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got some good answers in the comments, I just wanted to add that you can achieve what you'd like without the need of loops

```
mylist_csv <- mylist[grepl("csv",names(mylist))]
lapply(1:length(mylist_csv), function(i) write.csv(mylist_csv[[i]], paste0(i, ".csv")) )

mylist_xlsx <- mylist[grepl("xls|xlsx", names(mylist))]
lapply(1:length(mylist_xls ), function(i) write.xlsx(mylist_xlsx[[i]], paste0(i, ".xlsx")) )
```

This code separates your list into csv and xlsx lists, then writes each element of the respective list to csv and xlsx files. It keeps the same naming convection as you've already chosen.

Comment: I think the explicit for loop in OP's question is nicer than the hidden for loop in `lapply` here. Bugs are easy in anonymous functions like this. Case in point, your code is not equivalent, it saves the files as `1.csv`, `2.csv`, ...., whereas OP's code keeps the filenames in `mylist`.

Comment: If OP's operation was vectorized, then this approach would be cleaner, but `write.csv` and `write.xlsx` is going to happen one-at-a-tiime anyway, and in this case the `for` loop seems easier to read and less bug-prone to me.

Comment: @GregorThomas OPs naming convention is `paste0(i, ".xlsx")` where we have `i in 1:length(mylist)` so the naming convention should be the same as OPs. If OP wanted the names to be passed on he could have called `write.csv(mylist[[i]], names(mylist)[[i]])`

Comment: Ah - you're right. (But I assume and hope OP wants the filenames...  files named `1.csv`, `2.csv`, `3.csv` is a pretty poor result for most use cases)